# Bash While readline from standard in with no failure upon completion

Tags: bash, file-io

In bash, if I write a script that does the following,

```
while read -r line </dev/stdin; do 
...
done | parallel do_something_else
```

It works great.  No errors.

However, when I place the script inside a make recipe, make believes the script to have failed with an error...presumably because the while loop failed at the end of stdin.

How does one read all lines in stdin line by line without returning a failure condition when the end of the input is reached?

Comment: The exit status of a pipeline is the status of the last command, so it should be the status of `parallel`, not the `while read` loop.

Comment: A `while read` loop is not considered to have failed when it gets to the end of stdin.

Comment: BTW, there's no point in using `</dev/stdin`, that's where `read` reads from by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make` will run each command in a separate shell.  Consider:

```
$ cat Makefile
separate:
    echo $$$$
    echo $$$$

together:
    echo $$$$; \
    echo $$$$

$ make separate
echo $$
87214
echo $$
87215

$ make together
echo $$; \
    echo $$
87223
87223
```

Remember that in a bourne-like shell (my default being bash), `$$` expands to the PID of the shell.  but since `$` is also special in a `Makefile`, we must replace each `$` with its escaped version, `$$`.  Thus `$$` becomes `$$$$` with each of the two dollar signs replaced.

In the `together` target, I added a trailing `\` to prevent this behavior.  With those lines concatenated, I also had to add a `;` between the `echo`s.

If any of the `make` steps (ie separate commands) fails, `make` fails at that point.  So each of the commands must return `0` if the job is to succeed.  Take note, however, that you'll probably *want* `make` to fail in most error cases.  I would typically use an `if` conditional to handle these circumstances in bash scripts, and then execute the script with `-e` so that any error in the script is surfaced.

In light of these requirements and this behavior, I conclude that by far the easiest way to write and debug a shell command that will be executed by `make` is to put it in a separate executable file:

```
$ cat t.sh
#!/bin/bash -e
echo $$
echo $$

$ ls -l ./t.sh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 danfarrell  staff  31 Dec 26 16:35 ./t.sh

$ cat Makefile
script:
    ./t.sh

$ make script
./t.sh
88593
88593
```

You can then choose to exit with the exit code you choose at shell script completion.  Exit `0` when you want `make` to consider the execution a success.